# How to debug "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed"?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-errors

I'm unable to debug this:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: post_employee.employee_id

I'm saving value through my inbuilt admin then it's working fine, but when I am editing those values then it's raising integrityError. Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desgnation = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee)



def create_profile(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        Employee.objects.create(employee = kwargs['instance'])
post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=Person)
```

Errors

```
IntegrityError at /admin/post/person/1/change/
UNIQUE constraint failed: post_employee.employee_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/post/person/1/change/
Django Version: 2.0.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: post_employee.employee_id
```

In database i am seeing  `employee_id - integer - employee_id NOT NULL UNIQUE`

Is this IntegerityError coming for this UNIQUE, then how to correct it? I want to remove this integrity error.

Comment: On every save you are creating a new Employee with existing id(UNIQUE) value set from `kwargs`. What are you trying to do overall?

Comment: @VinayP  Sir I was practicing django signals.i'm doing a payslip management project where i want, when we will create a employee id,its details will be automatically dumped in different  models who share same variables like name,department,date of join etc, thats why i was practicing signals in this above code, but when im editing person model after creating it,it gives Integrity-error, i want to remove this integrity error. How can i do it Sir?

Comment: @VinayP Sir please tell me how to undo that unique from post_save method.

Comment: Why you want to update a model on save, you search a corresponding Employee entry in view and update that.